# Styling jQuery UI range slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I had to use jQuery UI for the first time, and I'm in a fight with it. I'm trying to create this slider:
[image]

But I realy don't know, how to edit these `.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle` etc. nothing is working for me. Even this doesn't work:

```
 .ui-slider-handle
 {
     background: url('../../img/slider/slide-dot.png') !important;
     width:9px !important;
     height:9px !important;
     top:0px !important;
     border:none !important;
 }
```

url is this dot:
[image]

But no luck for me, after this hangle just disspaears.

Btw., same with the background of the slider, whitch is this:
[image]

Could please somebody point me out of this?

I found this "perfect" codepen, just want to edit for my theme: https://codepen.io/ignaty/pen/EruAe

Thank you for your time, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the class, that'll increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> ```
> .ui-slider-handle.ui-slider-handle {
>      background: url('../../img/slider/slide-dot.png') !important;
>      width:9px !important;
>      height:9px !important;
>      top:0px !important;
>      border:none !important;
>   }
> ```